# external css files break jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Am new to node.js and am sorry if the answer to this question is too obvious

i build my app logic with all the routes and views and it work all fine , till i wanted to extend more styles to my views which i used Jade to build them as am using Express, the only change i did is i included bootstrap to my layout.jade

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
```

and my app break with 500 error.
note the bootstrap.min.css located in the public folder, also i noticed that in the console i got the right response before the error.

here is the error i got :

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
>   "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\mySpace\myApp\views"at Function.app.render
>   (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\mySpace\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:493:17)

app.js

```
  /*
* @ db the string to connect the database as its used in mongoose_connection to store sessions.
*
*/
module.exports = function(items, db){
    var express = require('express');
    // Include the module to enable session using connect-mongo
    var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
    // Include the module auth that using passpord module to authnticate user.
    var passport = require('./auth');
    // Include stylus module.
    var stylus = require('stylus');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('static-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var routes = require('./routes')(items);
    var app = express();

    // Compile function for stylus.
     function compile(str, path) {
        return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
     }

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');


    app.use(favicon());
    app.use(logger('dev'));


    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    app.use(cookieParser());


    //Middleware to store sessions 
    app.use(express.session({
        secret : 'keyboard cat',
        store : new mongoStore({
           mongoose_connection : db 
        })
    }));


    // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
    // persistent login sessions (recommended).
    // using passport as application midleware.
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    // telling session to use session in express.
    app.use(passport.session());



    //stylus middleware
    app.use(stylus.middleware(
        {
            src: __dirname + '/public',
            compile: compile
        }
    ));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    /*
    *Middleware to modifiy the header.
    */
    app.use(function(req,res,next){             
        res.set ('X-Powered-By' , 'Myapp');
        next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);

    app.put('/app/setItem/:id', routes.setItem);
    app.get('/app/findAllItem', routes.findAllitem);
    app.get('/app/findById/:id',routes.findById);
    app.get('/app/getJitems',routes.getJitems);

    /*
    *The routes of the login process 3 routes
    *@ the login form
    *@ the login post information and checking 
    *@ the success redirect route
    */

    // login form route
    app.get('/login', routes.login);
    //  check user route
   app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        successRedirect: '/user'
    }));
    //success login route
    app.get('/user', routes.user);

    /// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    /// error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });
    return app;
}
```

Comment: can you post your node.js files(like app.js)?

Comment: try adding `href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" and put bootstrap file in `stylesheets` folder. Better give your code.

Comment: `secret : 'keyboard cat',` - don't use default values in production code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it can't find "bootstrap.min.css", your 404 handler throws an error rather than generating a response, and you have no template for rendering error responses.

There are three problems you need to fix here:

- Assuming bootstrap.min.css is in the root "public" directory and is meant to be used site-wide, it should be linked with the absolute path "/bootstrap.min.css", like so:

  ```
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="/bootstrap.min.css")
  ```

  Note the leading slash. Without the slash, a path like "bootstrap.min.css" is interpreted as a sibling of the current location, meaning that its inclusion on a page like "/users/500/example" would lead the browser to look for it at "/users/500/bootstrap.min.css".
- Your "404 handler" should actually send a response, rather than throwing an error.
- You should either:

  - create an error template,
  - replace the res.render call in the error handler with res.send,
  - or delete the error handler altogether and fall back to Express's default error handler.

Comment: i have changed the code to `link(rel="stylesheet", href="/bootstrap.min.css")` , but still get the same error. i really start to think i missed up my views but, they work fine without including any css or js files.